# Publicar aplicacion 3 capas en Azure. DUDAS!

Tags: c#, azure

tengo una duda al respecto de como publicar mi aplicacion en Azure. Resulta que tengo 3 proyectos uno seria la capa de datos que es una biblioteca de clases, el otro capa negocio que tambien es una biblioteca de clases y el ultimo un web api. Todos tiene sus respecticas refenrencias.
¿ Como serian los pasos para publicar mi aplicacion ?

Siempre que subi mis soluciones a azure tenian un solo proyecto. En este caso como procedo

Comment: Click derecho en el proyecto de WebAPI -> Publicar -> Seguir los pasos que digan Azure.

Comment: Cuanto tienes varios projectos y publicas el proyecto principal, las librerias se integran (en este caso a tu web api) como archivos .dll en el folder donde publiques, por ejemplo si creas un proyecto de consola este va generar un archivo .exe, si este proyecto de consola le agregas referencias de otros proyectos en la misma solucion, esos otros proyectos van a generar sus propios archivos y estos van a ser inlcuidos cuando compiles el proyecto principal ejemplo: consolaApp.exe, liberia1.dll, libreria2.dll

Comment: Como menciona @fredyfx solo tienes que publicar el proyecto principal, los demas proyectos se integran automaticmante si estan referenciados a este.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por las repuestas

Comment: Una vez que lo logres, adjunta la respuesta y los pasos que seguiste, esto será de gran ayuda para más personas que tienen el mismo escenario. Recuerda marcar como aceptada la respuesta. Saludos :D